# Без понятия, как расставить знаки

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, деепричастный-оборот, пояснение

`Я делаю это(,) как хочу(,) (—) не сильно заморачиваясь.`

С деепричастным оборотом вообще не понимаю, как поступить. Похоже на пояснительную конструкцию, где части взаимозаменяемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я делаю это **как хочу**, не сильно заморачиваясь.*

**Пояснение**

В данном случае "как хочу" — **устойчивое** сочетание по [Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146). Однородные отношения с деепричастным оборотом.

Comment: Однородные отношения с деепричастным оборотом? Есть ссылка на источник?)

Comment: Ссылка?  Может, так договоримся?)  Деепричастный оборот по значению сближается с наречием  и используется как обстоятельство образа действия.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, понял